# Converting JIRA priority to Greenhopper Ranking

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I have an existing project that uses Priority to prioritize tickets.  I'd like to convert this project to a Greenhopper project, but I can't figure out how to do a one-time ordering of my backlog ordered by priority.

How can I do a one-time re-order of my Greenhopper backlog ranked in order of their old priority field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that there MUST be a better way, however here's how I did it.

I created a separate Quick Filter for each of my priorities, eg. one each for P0, P1, P2, etc.

I created a separate Sprint for each priority, eg. one each for P0, P1, P2, etc., one each in that order.

For each priority, I enabled the quick filter for that priority, selected all of the stories in the backlog (which are all of the same priority), then dragged those stories to the corresponding Sprint.

Once I was done doing that, there were no more stories in the backlog.

Then, I deleted each sprint in backward order.  So first I deleted P4, then P3, then P2, etc.  With each deletion, the stories from that sprint were added to the top of the backlog.

When I was done, I had a list of stories in my backlog ordered by priority.

Then I deleted the priority quickfilters.

Comment: Good workaround for a one-off task. Setting the new GH6 Rank field programatically looks trickier than this.

Comment: Fairly quick and achieves the desired outcome. Nice one.

Comment: I just did nearly the same, but just created one quick filter (editing it after each step), starting at second-lowest priority. Each time I'd hit the filter, select everything in backlog, unclick the quick filter (leaving everything still selected), then right click and select 'To top of backlog'. By the time I was done, the highest-priority are all at the top, and the lowest priority (which I never moved) were sitting at the bottom.